# Show multiple line graphs in one Label using echarts js

Tags: javascript, echarts

Currently i have following output [image]
But i want this output as follows in which multiple line graphs in different Label. Also double legend and label names. [image]
I tried many ways but didnt worked. Referred document from official website. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Plugin used apache echarts js.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?  I am looking for an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change `series.type` to `line` and remove `stack`. Also maybe you need to place each series to own `yAxis` but it's hard to say without code.